# How to install Hive on Redhat?

Tags: hadoop, hive, redhat

I have Hadoop configured on my Redhat system and running fine. But I would like to know the detailed steps to install HIVE.

I had referred the following tutoral https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted#GettingStarted-InstallationandConfiguration but couldn't find it useful.

Need some help regarding the installation of HIVE on top of Hadoop in Redhat linux

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are facing?I find this page really useful and to the point.

Comment: Getting the following error when $HIVE_HOME/bin/hive is executed :  Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Permission denied
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
        at java.io.File.checkAndCreate(File.java:1704)
        at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1792)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:115)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error shows that you don't have proper permissions. Do you have permissions to write to the directory which you have specified as the value of **hadoop.tmp.dir**?Or **dfs.data.dir** if you have added it in your hdfs-site.xml?

Are you able to write to HDFS directly(without Hive)??

Comment: Changed the permissions, but now the error status has been moved to the location : - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ALLOW_UNQUOTED_CONTROL_CHARS
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDTFJSONTuple.<clinit>(GenericUDTFJSONTuple.java:59)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)

Comment: Looks like you have hit this : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-3581 . What version of Hadoop and Hive are you using. Please make sure you have compatible Jackson jars. Replace the Jackson related jars in your HADOOP_HOME/lib with the jars available in HIVE_HOME/lib and see if it helps.

Comment: Is it possible to know which Jar file is causing the issue...?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you give proper permissions! Use chmod if necessary, run as root user/sudo commands.

Answer (score 0):

You have check you are whether o n User like Charnjeet or hduser.Some command are not proper work on hduser..so use  defult user like Charnjeet and sudo command...